# Generate postfix without binary tree

Tags: algorithm, go, binary-tree, abstract-syntax-tree

Can we generate a postfix format string from an expression without creating a binary tree or AST tree

For example, I have an expression `exp = "1 + 2 * 3 * ( 4 - 2 ) + A / B "`
and I want to generate a postfix string = `"1 2 3 * 4 2 - * + A B / +"`

Comment: @Henry Sorry my bad, edited

Comment: Have a look at the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: See http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall09/V22.0102-002/lectures/InfixToPostfixExamples.pdf